# Using two different copies of an identical std::view

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I'm trying to use views in a commercial application, and noticed an inconsistency between gcc and Visual Studio.

In the code below, calling `transformed()` twice returns two different, apparently incompatible views.  In gcc 11 (on godbolt), the code executes without issue, even with extra debugging, but in Visual Studio 16.11 with `-std:c++latest`, it asserts:

> cannot compare incompatible transform_view iterators

I would like my function to be callable just as if it were returning a `const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &` so the caller doesn't have to worry about temporaries.  It seems that I could make my transformed view a member of my class, initialize it in the constructor, and return that, but I don't even know how to declare it.

I'm assuming that Visual Studio is correct and my code is illegal, but even if my code *should* be legal, it still has to work.  We have a 10,000,000-line code base and a lot of non-expert C++ programmers, and I need the core to be robust and not have hidden gotchas like this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

struct X
{
    std::vector<int> m_values{ 1,2,3 };
    auto transformed() const
    {
        return std::ranges::views::transform(m_values, [](int i) {
            return std::pair{ i, i + i };
            });
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    for (auto [a, b] : x.transformed())
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;

    if (x.transformed().begin() != x.transformed().end()) // asserts in visual studio.
        std::cout << "not empty";

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hPWYGn9dY

Comment: you can't compare iterators from two different views. Imagine you have two vectors: `std::vector<int> a; std::vector<int> b;` your if statement would essentially do `if(a.begin() != b.end())` - which is undefined behaviour because you're comparing iterators from two different containers. it's the same concept with views - whenever you're dealing with iterators, both must come from the same container.

Comment: you could fix this by changing your if statement to e.g. `if (auto view = x.transformed(); view.begin() != view.end())` that way you're comparing iterators from the same view.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that I could make my transformed view a member of my class,
> initialize it in the constructor, and return that, but I don't even
> know how to declare it.

You can turn `X` into a template class, and construct the member `transform_view` through the passed lambda, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template<class F>
struct X {
  std::vector<int> m_values{1,2,3};
  decltype(m_values | std::views::transform(std::declval<F>())) m_transformed;

  X(F fun) : m_transformed(m_values | std::views::transform(std::move(fun))) { }
  const auto& transformed() const { return m_transformed; }
};

int main() {
  X x([](int i) { return std::pair{i, i + i}; });
  for (auto [a, b] : x.transformed())
    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;

  if (x.transformed().begin() != x.transformed().end())
    std::cout << "not empty";
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/oKj6oKdzv)

Another way is to use `std::function`, which makes your `X` need not be a template class:

```
struct X {
  using Fun = std::function<std::pair<int, int>(int)>;
  std::vector<int> m_values{1,2,3};
  decltype(m_values | std::views::transform(Fun{})) m_transformed;

  X(Fun fun = [](int i) { return std::pair{i, i + i}; }) 
  : m_transformed(m_values | std::views::transform(std::move(fun))) { }
  const auto& transformed() const { return m_transformed; }
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/MM1q1G9v3)

Comment: Thanks, perfect (although a little more verbose than I'd like given the simplicity of the original, but that's C++ for you). I also did the non-template version starting with your code at https://godbolt.org/z/4TxWsrfYY.

Comment: @RobL keep in mind though that `for (auto [a, b] : X().transformed())` will also not result in a compile time error, but will blow up at runtime (X will be freed before the for loop runs) [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4654c11s3)

Comment: @康桓瑋 I updated the code derived from your solution https://godbolt.org/z/jaqz1Wv71.  This has an additional advantage for me that I have a function returning the transformation which can be called as a free function in other places. Thanks again.

Comment: @Turtlefight agreed. For me, the object X is our main database and is unlikely to be used in that way. But, that's a general C++ gotcha, std::string().c_str() passed has the same issue.  

If X were frequently were created as a temporary, then this solution of holding the transformed view could possibly make things worse (maybe).